# How do you manage training data in the local version of Vanna?

Tags: python

The hosted version of Vanna has a [`vn.get_training_data(...)`](https://vanna.ai/docs/vanna.html#get_training_data) function.

However, when I try to run [locally following the examples](https://vanna.ai/docs/local.html) there's no equivalent function for retrieving and deleting training data.

How do I manage the training data when using the local version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_training_data` function is not in the [base class](https://vanna.ai/docs/vanna/base/base.html).

In order to manage the training data, you would need to subclass the local version and add your own training data management functions. That being said, it's likely that this will be added into the base class soon.